# Django password storage

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-viewsets

I'm having some trouble storing passwords with Django REST Framework. Basically, the password of the superuser was stored correctly (it looks like this: pbkdf2_sha256$320000$iSRRmEm7YbZHoYzd4wJt2v$Yht0x74n4DSDvM0JjnzddSPU8sp0ahmog0ZAsdT4j84=). However, when I try to do the same POST request using Postman or the Django view, the password is stored in plaintext. For example, when I try to do a POST request using the following data

```
{
    "username": "kelly.jackson",
    "first_name": "Kelly",
    "last_name": "Jackson",
    "email": "kelly.jackson@gmail.com",
    "password": "^qT!4pVl40"
}
```

it looks like this

```
        {
            "id": 2,
            "password": "^qT!4pVl40",
            "last_login": null,
            "is_superuser": false,
            "username": "kelly.jackson",
            "first_name": "Kelly",
            "last_name": "Jackson",
            "email": "kelly.jackson@gmail.com",
            "is_staff": false,
            "is_active": true,
            "date_joined": "2022-04-12T20:49:20.318685Z",
            "groups": [],
            "user_permissions": []
        }
```

But the password should be encrypted using a PBKDF, similar to the superuser. How can I force Django to use a PBKDF when storing passwords?

My `serializers.py` looks like this

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

and my `views.py` looks like this.

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer


# Create your views here.

class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

change the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` in your `settings.py`

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Django rest framework doesn't encrypt the passwords automatically. You 'll have to explicitly do that. Use make_password function from django contrib or if the insance is available you can simply do `instance.set_password(<password here>)`

Override the create/Update method of the serializer:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Similarly for update

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'password' in validated_data:
            validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        return super().update(instance,validated_data)
```